# htaccess rewrite rule ignores request uri

Tags: .htaccess

I'm using Apache/2.4.10 and i'm using these rewrite rules

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(htm|php|js|css|htc|png|gif|jpe?g|ico|xml|csv|txt|swf|flv|mp4|webm|ogv|mp3|ogg|oga|eot|otf|tt[cf]|woff2?|svgz?|pdf|gz)$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

If I navigate (testesd in Chrome or Firefox) to "example.com/my-page" the Url gets rewritten to "www.example.com/index.php" (the homepage instead of my-page).

I tried replacing the last two lines with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI}
```

I also changed the order of the Rewrite Cond/Rules (ie putting the last two line right below the RewriteBase...

I'm sure this did exactly what it was supposed to on a similar webserver.

Please help, what am I overlooking?

Thank you so much.

Comment: when you put the last two on top, which format did you use? with or without request uri?

Comment: @inarilo I tried both actually.

Comment: you ended it with $ so it's not matching

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Can you point me to which $ I should change to what? thank you!

Comment: ^example\.com$ will only match example.com, and not example.com/whatever because $ signifies the end of the string being matched (and ^ the beginning)..

Comment: I see. But the RewriteCond seems to trigger, just not with adding the REQUEST_URI. What do I have to do to make it work? I just deleted the $ - but still the same.

Comment: you can try `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^.+$ http://www.example.com/%1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: Put it in the beginning, otherwise i think it will match and go to index.php